# MEANjs Passport callbacks not working (404)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, oauth-2.0, passport.js, meanjs

I'm building a web app with [MEANjs](http://meanjs.org) and I'm having some trouble with the Oauth callbacks for Facebook, Twitter, and Google+ (lnkedin works fine). Basically everything works, but the callback gives me 'Page Not Found' `Error: /api/auth/facebook/[object%20Object] is not a valid path.`

If i navigate to another page, I find that I am logged in. The routes seem to be correct, as generated by MEANjs

```js
app.route('/api/auth/facebook').get(users.oauthCall('facebook', {
    scope: ['email']
  }));
  app.route('/api/auth/facebook/callback').get(users.oauthCallback('facebook'));
```

I've checked the callbacks in the facebook app setup and they're fine. Totally stumped. Would love any help or advice.

Thanks.

Comment: take a look at angular-fullstack implementations - https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack/tree/master/app/templates/server/auth(auth)

Comment: [This](https://github.com/meanjs/mean/issues/1290) might be a related issue

Comment: Thanks @user3632710 that led me to the answer, will post it below.

Comment: What's the status of this issue?

Answer (score 4):

The comments by @user3632710 led me to the issue that was indeed a URL concatenation issue ass @Paul suggested. The offending code is at line 121 of `modules/users/server/controllers/users/users.authentication.server.controller.js`

which is: `return res.redirect(redirectURL || sessionRedirectURL || '/');`

for now i've just commented this out and redirected to the root, which is fine for my purposes but inelegant generally:

```
return res.redirect('/');
```

Thanks for all your help, hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Thanks @theSiberman. this helped me, but you let me know how it got resolved

Answer (score 0):

Whatever code is building  your URL is clearly not doing it right.  It looks like you're calling toString() (directly or indirectly) on an object, and that's being concatenated with the URL in question, which your server-side routes don't know how to handle.  The code you've posted is incomplete for helping us find the error for you, but I'd look in whatever logic is building that URL.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, the issue was to do with the URL builder, the comments above led me to the culprit, will post answer below. Cheers.